# How to create index for table having 30 columns where Select statement is generated dynamically

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design, plsql

I have a table containing language translations. It has 30 columns for 30 languages.

My requirement is to search from all columns for a particular word (say "hello").

I dynamically create Select statement:

**Select * from Languages
where {English = "hello" 
OR French = "hello"
OR German = "hello"}**

**Statement inside {} is generated dynamically.**

If I have to index such a table, how do I do that?

Will I have to create one index for all 30 columns or create seperate 30 indexes for each column?

Please suggest better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have 30 columns, you should use a table with a column for language name, and a column for the word, and an id to associate the 30 rows together.  Then you can simply query for `WORD = 'hello'`.

If you absolutely must keep 30 columns, you will need to create 30 indexes, and the performance of the query will be 30 times slower than it needs to be.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I understand what you are saying, but because of certain architectural issues, we were not able to do that...for now we have 30 columns to deal with...can there be a solution to this?

Comment: This is a MUCH smarter approach.  Your query will be much faster and you are constrained by the number of fields.

Comment: As @amccausl suggests, you could change the underlying table structure, and present a similar 30-column result for the rest of your system.

Comment: WHat would happen if I index only the id column instead of indexing all 30 columns? Will that improve my search performance?

Comment: If you only index the id column, then only queries against the id column will be fast.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a second table that contains [id, lang, value], and index it by the id and value.  You can set up a view that replicates the table you are working with from this, or vice versa, and index the view

Answer (score 0):

If you must have all 30 columns, you will need to separately index each column.

Comment: Will that increase search performance when I query using Select statment?

Comment: As compared to querying it without the indexes? Yes, for sure. Inserting rows will be slower though.